# Reponsive sidebar/content area html css

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar, responsive

I'm trying to make 2 divs responsive but I'm having a lot more trouble than I should.

Div2 is by default 100% width.
Div1 is toggleable, when that happens the width should be 50% for both divs. When toggled off div2 should return to 100% width.

```css
/* Main App */
 #app { 
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%; 
    }
 #app #div1 { 
      width: 50%; 
      float: left;
    }
 #app #div2 { 
      max-width: 100%; 
      min-width: 50%; 
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div id="app">

 <div id="div1">
  toggled content here
 </div>
  
   <div id="div2">
    main content here
 </div>

</div>
```

I'm sure this is possible without using JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with tables or css flex box model (IE10+). Anyway if you are toggling Div2 by Javascript, so you should be able to toggle a class on div1, e.g.:

```
$('#someToggle').click(function() {
   $('#div2').toggle();
   $('#div1').toggleClass('full-width');
});
```

Then with CSS:

```
#app #div1.full-width { width: 100%; float: none; }
```